# Вывести URL для текущей вкладки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Добрый День. Для тестового примера хочу попробовать вывести URL для текущей вкладки. 
 Мой ***manifest.json***

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Chrome Extension",
"description": "MyExtension",
"icons": {
    "16": "img/favicon.png",
    "48": "img/48.png"
},
"version": "0.1",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/content.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://*/*", "http://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/default_icon.png",
    "default_title": "Get URL"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "css": ["css/style.css"]
}],
    "short_name": "GetURL"
}
```

Код в ***content.js***

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, tabs => {
  alert(tabs[0].url);
});
```

Проблема в том, что URL выводится только для первой каждой текущей вкладки. Менял ***lastFocusedWindow*** на ***currentWindow*** но это проблему не решило. Подскажите, что делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что background скрипты живут в едином экземпляре, в фоне расширения.

Ваш скрипт стартует вместе с запуском расширения и в соответствии кодом тут же выводит активную вкладку.

Для того чтобы отслеживать переключение активных вкладок можно сделать так:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    // можно получить детальное инфо по табу:
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tabInfo) {
         console.log(tabInfo.url);
    });
});
```

Обратите внимание, что во время возникновения этого события вкладка может не иметь URL. В таком случае поможет [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)

Еще рекомендую использовать имена вида content.js или content-script.js именно для [content скриптов](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: А в `activeInfo` нет `url`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, согласно [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) там только `tabId` и `windowId`